# creating <=> conditions with date format in R

Tags: r, datetime, parallel-processing

I have the following data frame:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
date<-c("23-01-08","01-11-07","30-11-07","17-12-07")
df<-data.frame(id,date)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

in the 4th column f my table I want to divide my data to calib and valid based on date such that where date <=2007-12-16 the forth column should be `calib` otherwise it should be `valid`

I have written the following lines:

```
for ( i in 1:4)
if (df[i,3]<=2007-12-16)(df[i,4]="calib")else (df[i,4]="valid")
```

The first problem is that by executing this command all cells in the 4th column will become `valid` and it seems that the date condition can not be processed appropriately. so my first question is that how can I solve this problem.

the second problem is that my real data frame has 600000 rows and executing this command will take hours. I wonder if there is any way to preform this command faster and with full CPU capacity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R is **vectorised** so you can do that in a single statement:

```
R> df <- within(df,state <- ifelse(date2<=as.Date("2007-12-16"),"calib","valid"))
R> df
  id     date      date2 state
1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 valid
2  2 01-11-07 2007-11-01 calib
3  3 30-11-07 2007-11-30 calib
4  4 17-12-07 2007-12-17 valid
R>
```

If `within`, `with`, or `transform` seem strange, you can also do it directly:

```
R> df$state <- ifelse(df$date2<=as.Date("2007-12-16"),"calib","valid")
R> df
  id     date      date2 state
1  1 23-01-08 2008-01-23 valid
2  2 01-11-07 2007-11-01 calib
3  3 30-11-07 2007-11-30 calib
4  4 17-12-07 2007-12-17 valid
R>
```